# Django: Filtering out duplicate query results

Tags: django, django-queryset

I have a model:

```
class Item(models.Model):
    date = models.DateField()
```

I would like to select one of these objects for each date, with no duplicates.

So if there were 100 items in the database, which had dates of either 1/1/12 or 1/2/12, I would want to return a list of two objects (one for 1/1/12 and one for 1/2/12).

I'm not sure of the terminology for this kind of query, so am having trouble searching for an answer.

I'm currently using this query:

```
item_list = Item.objects.distinct('date')
```

But it is not working as I expected.

Any help appriciated.

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are you using Postgress SQL? Django documentation says distinct on fields works only with that DB. Also you have to use `order_by` before using `distinct()`.

Check documentation : [django distinct](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#distinct)

Comment: Thanks! Didn't notice the bit about requiring Postgress.